# Ordering records by a field only with respect to records with the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an EAV table in SQL which as usual has several records for each ID.  Each of these records has a numerical value in a column called 'weight' and I'm trying to sort this table so that for each ID the records are ranked in descending order of weight.  This is going to be a one off process because I intend to make sure that data is sorted when it goes into the table in future.

Also is the normal protocol for doing something like this to `SELECT` all of the data, sort it the way you want, and then use the `REPLACE` command to replace the old data in the table?

I know that I can do this for one id by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 'X' ORDER BY weight DESC
```

but I need to somehow do this for each id in my table.  How is this normally done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will ALWAYS return the data in the order you wish in this case:

```
SELECT * from theTable order by  id, weight desc
```

you do not store the data in any particular order. (even if you try this will not matter).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `WHERE` clause and add `id` to `ORDER BY`. This way, your result set will be ordered first by `id`, and for each `id`, it will be ordered by `weight`.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id, weight DESC
```